# jQuery iframe cache , always load the same

Tags: jquery, iframe, browser-cache

I have big problem with function i create for works with jquery and create in the fly one iframe

```
jQuery("#popup_content").append("<div id=adm_popup><iframe src='"+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash='+id width='100%' marginwidth='0' height='800' marginheight='0' align='middle' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>")
```

I try use the solution and put random hash in the url of iframe but continue no works fine and always load the same url , i need reload the page for when i go over the link load other page when open

It´s possible use append for create in the fly iframes , etc and no problem with scr of url and cache ?

Thank´s , Regards !

**FINALLY I FIX WITH THIS :**

```
jQuery("#popup_content").append("<div class=adm_popup><iframe id='ifr' src='"+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash="+id+"' width='100%' marginwidth='0' height='800' marginheight='0' align='middle' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0'></iframe></div>");

jQuery("#ifr").attr("src",""+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash="+id+"");
```

I force Reload the scr other time and finally load each link with his content and no get cache problem , i think this only happend into firefox

Regards

Comment: Could you please post more javascript. Where `iframer1`, `id` and `iframer2` is defined. Because it's probably a scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be including the word 'id' in the string, rather than its value. But there's also no evidence of your "random hash" anyway:

```
<iframe src='"+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash='+id width='100%' marginwidth='0' height='800' marginheight='0' align='middle' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                                                    ^^^^ here
```

Add in, above the code you already have:

```
var hash = < create random hash >
```

and then the jQuery line becomes:

```
<iframe src='"+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash="+hash+"' width='100%' marginwidth='0' height='800' marginheight='0' align='middle' scrolling='auto' frameborder='0'></iframe>
                                                     ^^^^^^ here
```

There is no problem with dynamically creating IFRAMEs that I've come across, although there are other (possibly better) ways of avoiding the cache if you have control over the IFRAME's content as well.

Comment: Nothing continue load the same url , i need reload the all the web for get other content with iframe , all time get cache into iframe and no load differents urls

Comment: @user2501504 Please don't take this personally, but I'm afraid I'm not sure what you're meaning by this comment?

Comment: Finally i fix add this jQuery("#ifr").attr("src",""+ iframer1 + ""+id+""+iframer2+"&hash="+id+""); , i put this in my post now